# How to NodeJS require inside TypeScript file?

Tags: node.js, typescript

How do I load a regular NodeJS module (from `node_modules`) from within a `TypeScript` class?

When I try to compile `.ts` file that contains:

```
var sampleModule = require('modulename');
```

Compiler prompts that I can't use require in this scope. (That line is at the beginning of the file).

Comment: Can you show us your code ( original and compiled one )? I thought that `require` can be used anywhere, it does not depend on scope.

Comment: Yes, but have to be declared and is not declared in default lib.d.ts as Valentin suggested.

Comment: TypeScript should not complain if the target is set to ES6 using `"target": "es6",` in the `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Typescript will always complain when it is unable to find a symbol. The compiler comes together with a set of default definitions for `window`, `document` and such specified in a file called `lib.d.ts`. If I do a grep for `require` in this file I can find no definition of a function `require`. Hence, we have to tell the compiler ourselves that this function will exist at runtime using the `declare` syntax:

```
declare function require(name:string);
var sampleModule = require('modulename');
```

On my system, this compiles just fine.

Comment: Thank you. This will work for all functions not declared. Better solution I have found is to get node.d.ts from typescript samples and reference it. Than you have everything. There is also express.d.ts.

Comment: I think you can also do `import sampleModule = module('modulename')`

Comment: Yeah but node.d.ts is currently at `v0.8.8`. Better to use the approach by @Valentin and then use say WebStorm IDE that can download definitions for the version of Node you are running and give you autocomplete etc on that.

Comment: @Radek How do you do that? I use WebStorm 7.0.2 (latest) Btw I don't find the script node.d.ts, where does it is located? Thx.

Comment: @Vadorequest this should help: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Comment: @Radek I found the file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.d.ts , in addition I plugged the declare function require(name:string); into that file so that it would always be automatically available, vs adding that snippet to every script

Comment: Include in ts file
/// <reference path="node.d.ts" />

Comment: In case you missed it (as I did), you can get the `*.d.ts` files from [http://definitelytyped.org](http://definitelytyped.org/) (as @Jesse said in his answer below), and you include them in your project using `/// <reference path="path/to/your/file.d.ts" />` in your .ts file (as @FacePalm said in the above comment).

Answer (score 94):

The correct syntax is:

```
import sampleModule = require('modulename');
```

or

```
import * as sampleModule from 'modulename';
```

Then compile your TypeScript with `--module commonjs`.

If the package doesn't come with an `index.d.ts` file and its `package.json` doesn't have a `"typings"` property, `tsc` will bark that it doesn't know what `'modulename'` refers to. For this purpose you need to find a `.d.ts` file for it on http://definitelytyped.org/, or write one yourself.

If you are writing code for Node.js you will also want the `node.d.ts` file from http://definitelytyped.org/.

Comment: I followed this approach, using "import * as $s from 'scriptjs';" since I am using TypeScript. The CKEDITOR.replace() command seems to execute, and I get what looks like a valid DOM element from it, however nothing changes in the browser (still a textarea) and my editor.on( 'contentDom', ...) callbacks (also installed inside the $s callback) never get called. Any idea what's up?

Answer (score 57):

The best solution is to get a copy of Node's type definitions. This will solve all kinds of dependency issues, not only `require()`. This was previously done using packages like `typings`, but as Mike Chamberlain mentioned, Typings are deprecated. The modern way is doing it like this:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Not only will it fix the compiler error, it will also add the definitions of the Node API to your IDE.

Comment: This worked for me too! But what I don't understand is that I had it installed globally (ie: `npm install -g @types/node`) but that didn't work?

Comment: What if types module is not available in npm ?

Comment: @SudharshanNair there are a lot of types defined by the DefinitelyTyped project.

Other options include contrinuting to Definitely typed declaring types within your own project, or using without type defs,

Answer (score 3):

Use typings to access node functions from TypeScript:

```
typings install env~node --global
```

If you don't have typings  install it:

```
npm install typings --global
```

Comment: Should be noted that typings is deprecated in favor of simply `npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Answer (score 1):

when loading typescript module I use module name with extension i.e.
".ts"

`const sampleModule = require('modulename.ts');`

FYI, in my case "node" command (v14.17.1) using ".ts" files directly without generating "*.js" files.