# Using Nodejs with Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, webserver, typescript

I would like to use Nodejs in my typescript project and downloaded node.d.ts from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/node

But VisualStudio finds a lot of errors in the .d.ts file. They're all basically the same:

> Error 2   exported interface 'Server' extends interface from private
>   module 'events'   C:\Users\lhk\Desktop\typescript-game\strategy
>   go\node\node-0.8.d.ts 236 37  node-0.8.d.ts

All the error messages complain that a private interface is extended.

I searched SO and found this question:
[nodejs require inside TypeScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742082/nodejs-require-inside-typescript-file)

One of the comments gives the advice to download node.d.ts from the Microsoft samples. I browsed the internet, found this article http://stackful.io/blog/typescript-nodejs-vim-and-linux-oh-my/ and downloaded the second version of node.d.ts , with the exact same result.

Where do I find a proper definitions file for nodejs and Typescript ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the 0.8.1-1 version of TypeScript, use the latest `node.d.ts` file from this github project:
https://github.com/soywiz/typescript-node-definitions

I was getting the same `exported interface` errors until I pulled the latest definition files from there.

Comment: great, this worked. I compared the two .d.ts files and found a curious difference. In the modules section, whenever another module is imported, the old version uses "import something=module("something")", but the new version changes this to "export import something=module("something")". Why is it all of a sudden legit to extend an interface of a private module, if that module is exported ? The whole construct does not make sense to me. Why does for example the module http "export import" the module events ? Am I now able to do something like http.events.SomethingfromEvents ?

Comment: The github project is fantastic, it solved another of my questions. If you would copy this answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084406/typescript-and-socket-io I would be glad to accept it

Comment: @lhk I haven't looked into the details as to why it works, I was just glad it did. I looked at your other question, but that question indicates you're already using the `socket.io.d.ts` file from the `soywiz` project so I'm confused as to why you want me to copy this answer there.

Comment: You're right, I mixed something up. I realized that this error occured in the socket.io.d.ts file, too, after I had posted this question. Then I switched to the new node.d.ts version and the error vanished in socket.io.d.ts. Since I had already solved the problem for the socket.io client, the error here was the only remaining one with socket.io. I'm sorry, I will now post my solution to the socket.io problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the heck is going on here.

I suspect that the current version of the (0.8.1~1) node.js package for Typescript broke some stuff. I've been running into this too. I tweaked the node.d.ts file and marked a couple things "export" instead of "declare" and that got me past my compilation issues, but I'm finding that the functions are not showing up in the current scope.

FWIW, I have been playing around with a personal fork of typescript-require and typescript-wrapper (both of which required some tweaking to work with 0.8.1~1) and I'm wasn't too certain that everything is working as well as it should be, so I wasn't sure that the issue is my issue or something endemic to the current node/typescript.