# TypeScript and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, socket.io, typescript

I would like to use socket.io in my Typescript project, but I've only found .d.ts files for server-side typescript.

This is a nice example: https://github.com/soywiz/typescript-node-definitions/blob/master/socket.io.d.ts

It shows how to use TypeScript in combination with Socket.io. However on the client side it uses JavaScript.

What I need is a .d.ts file for client-side TypeScript, that resolves the error message from this line:

```
var socket=io.connect("localhost");
```

> The name "io" does not exist in the current  scope

Where can I find the appropriate definition file?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is @types/socket.io now, just install it by running:

`npm i --save @types/socket.io`

Comment: For the client side:  npm i --save @types/socket.io-client

Comment: What @sintetico82 said above is solid: `npm i --save-dev @types/socket.io-client` (`save-dev` is ok if your HTML will load the JavaScript payload from the SocketIO server), then in your TypeScript code `const socket=io();` will be automatically typed: `const socket: SocketIOClient.Socket`.

Comment: **NOTE:** `@types/socket.io-client` is a stub types definition. socket.io-client provides its own type definitions, so you do not need it installed.

Answer (score 14):

You should use [socket.io-client](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/2d4c4679bc2b509f27435a4f9da5e2de11258571/socket.io-client) d.ts file in the client and while using [socket.io](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/40506907409eed93e875064f01056dbf79149f91/socket.io) d.ts file on the server.

Answer (score 12):

I created my own .d.ts file, it's rather short but it works well:

```
declare var io : {
    connect(url: string): Socket;
};
interface Socket {
    on(event: string, callback: (data: any) => void );
    emit(event: string, data: any);
}
```

This declaration file can be imported to client side Typescript and the socket.io standard example will work, here's my Typescript version:

```
var socket=io.connect("localhost");
socket.on("news",(data:any)=>alert(data));
socket.emit("news","hello");
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside `@types/socket.io-client`, you can find the following type which is best suited for clients:

```js
const client: SocketIOClient.Socket = io('http://localhost');
```