# Nodejs require('this')(that) in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs

I'm using @awspilot/dynamodb in a node lambda function, but also using typescript.

A standard nodejs `var x = require('x')` becomes `import * as x from 'x'` in typescript no problem - but @awspilot/dynamodb needs the slightly more unusual:

```
var $db = new AWS.DynamoDB()
var awspilotDB = require('@awspilot/dynamodb')($db)
```

Is there a typescript-y way of rendering this as an `import` and still passing the extra parameter?

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require('@awspilot/dynamodb')` is returning a function. Therefore the following should work fine:

```
import * as DynamodbFactory from '@awspilot/dynamodb'
const awspilotDB = DynamodbFactory($db)
```

You can, of course, choose whatever name you like for `DynamodbFactory`.

---

Alternatively you can also use the require function with TypeScript as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12742371/4430124)

Comment: Thanks for explaining - and you answered so quickly it won't even let me accept it yet!