# Angular 4 Cannot find name Error

Tags: angular, jwt-simple

I'm using the jwt simple library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-simple

In one of my Typescript, I have the following:

```
const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const payload = { user: 'joesan' };
const secret = 'testtest';
```

Now when I run this application, it fails in the place where it has the require(...). It fails with the following message:

```
Cannot find name 'require'.
```

Any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here - [nodejs require inside TypeScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742082/nodejs-require-inside-typescript-file)

Typescript doesn't use the CommonJS method of dependency importing, so you'll have to tweak it a little.

First you need to make sure the allowJS option is set to true in your tsconfig.json flie.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
     ... 
    "allowJS": true,
     ...
     }
}
```

Now i'm pasting the best relevant answer from the link above

> The correct syntax is:
>
> import sampleModule = require('modulename'); or
>
> import * as sampleModule from 'modulename'; Then compile your
>   TypeScript with --module commonjs.
>
> If the package doesn't come with an index.d.ts file and it's
>   package.json doesn't have a "typings" property, tsc will bark that it
>   doesn't know what 'modulename' refers to. For this purpose you need to
>   find a .d.ts file for it on http://definitelytyped.org/, or write one
>   yourself.
>
> If you are writing code for Node.js you will also want the node.d.ts
>   file from http://definitelytyped.org/.

If you're using angular CLI, you could also just try adding it to the 'scripts' parameter in the angular-cli.json

```
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "main": "src/main.ts",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [   // HERE 
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "tsconfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
      "mobile": false
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `import jwt-simple` in place of the require statement.