# In Angular 5, how can I import NPM modules with no @types

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying Angular 5, starting a project from angular-cli. In this project, I would like to use a NPM module : J2M (https://github.com/kylefarris/J2M), so I looked online and saw these two commands :

```
npm install j2m --save
npm install @types/j2m --save-dev
```

Unfortunately, @types/j2m doesn't exist at all. 
So I tried to find a way to define my own typings but didn't manage to succeed...

I'm using this code :

```
import * as J2M from "j2m";
...
console.log(J2M.toM(value));
```

But either "j2m" is not recognized, or "toM" is not a function, based on the samples I found online...

So, what's the proper way to import this module?

Thanks,

Comment: There isn't an `@types/j2m` package. You need to write your own types.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add the scripts into your `angular-cli.json` file.

Under the `scripts` property, add

```
'../node_modules/path/to/minified/js.js'
```

If a style is required, you must also add it under your `styles` property, in the same file.

Once you did that, **your library is imported**. This means you don't need to use such things as

```
import * from 'j2m';
```

But if you want to use a global variable without your IDE throwing errors, then you should add

```
declare var J2M: any;
```

with `J2M` being the exported, global function from your library (for instance, for MomentJS, this variable is called `moment`).

When you use a definition file, it just tells the CLI to automatically fetch the JS library, and gives you IDE auto-completion. With this solution, you don't have auto-completion, and you explicitly tells the CLI where to fetch the library.

Comment: Perfect ! Thats works :) Accepting as best solution.

Comment: Oh, another "problem" appeared when I tried to siwtch to the forked version of J2M, that uses "require('marked')

ReferenceError: require is not defined

And later on

TypeError: J2M is undefined

probably because it failed to import marked...

Comment: Then don't switch to it :D Otherwise, take a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742082/nodejs-require-inside-typescript-file) to resolve it