# Instantiate a class knowing the file path at runtime

Tags: node.js, typescript

How can I instantiate a class (with, say, a known empty constructor), for example:

at `api/EmptyClass1.ts`, I have:

```
export default class EmptyClass1 {

}
```

and, at `api/EmptyClass2.ts`, I have:

```
export default class EmptyClass2 {

}
```

I want this function:

```
function(filepath:string):any{
  return Object.fromFile(filepath); //this line is mock code
}
```

to return a new instance of either `EmptyClass1` or `EmptyClass2`, if the parameter `filepath:string` is `"api/EmptyClass1.ts"` or `"api/EmptyClass2.ts"`, respectively.

The files defining the classes may not be known at the time the function is written may include any number of files. Consequently, using the `import` statement for each class, then using a switch, or if-then statements is not an acceptable solution.

The .ts files defining the classes are transcoded to javascript and reside in the application .build folder as .js files.

I am using typescript on node.js (recent versions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `require` instead, and your problem will be solved. If the file may not exist, you can use [optional-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optional-require) if you want to have a fallback without using `try/catch`.

```
    function fromFile(filepath:string):any{
      // return Object.fromFile(filepath); //this line is mock code
      return require(filepath);
    }
```

Or just call `require` directly instead of wrapping it in another function.

Also check: 
[nodejs require inside TypeScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742082/nodejs-require-inside-typescript-file)

Comment: Is there any way to call require in a non-blocking manner? I assume this call is synchronous when used at runtime, and that it reads the file from the disk.

Comment: There is not, but require calls are cached, so each file will only be called once, and unless the files are huge, I don't think you'll have to worry. You can preload them dynamically if you want, before you start the server too.

Comment: require will only work if file exist in your project, what if  file exist outside the project in that case, Any suggestion how to do that?