# How to add types to require in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript

How can I have type annotations to an import using the require() function?
For instance I have this authenticate function from GCP Auth service:

```js
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
```

I see in the node_modules there's a index.d.ts file with type annotations for it:

```js
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';
export interface LocalAuthOptions {
    keyfilePath: string;
    scopes: string[] | string;
}
export declare function authenticate(options: LocalAuthOptions): Promise<OAuth2Client>;
```

But when I try to use the functions it shows as type any.
[image]

How can I add the type annotations to it?

Comment: Any reason you can't use import?

Comment: Related thread on vscode github issue: [https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77627](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77627). And related SO post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742082/how-to-nodejs-require-inside-typescript-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742082/how-to-nodejs-require-inside-typescript-file)