# TypeScript path mapping read JSON file

Tags: typescript

Im relatively new to TypeScript but i've just added path mapping to my project, however in some files I need to read in a JSON file to use as a fixture.

Much to my disappointment something like this does not work:

`const widgetFixture = require("@fixtures/widgets/widget.json");`

if I've defined my path mapping as such:

`"@fixtures/*": ["lib/fixtures/*"],`

All my other path mapping works, is there not a better way to point to this file? (File is in the `{root}/lib/fixtures/widgets`). Can you not use path mapping one such a file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to NodeJS require inside TypeScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742082/how-to-nodejs-require-inside-typescript-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `resolveJsonModule` tsconfig option and use

`import widgetFixture from "@fixtures/widgets/widget.json";`